# How to use proto files in googleapis-common-protos in Python?

Tags: python, google-api, protocol-buffers

I want to use proto files which are already defined at [googleapis/api-common-protos](https://github.com/googleapis/api-common-protos) in Python. For example

```
syntax = "proto3";

package com.example.service.rev0;

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";
import "google/rpc/code.proto";

message GenericExcInfo {

    google.rpc.Code status_code = 1;

    string name = 2;

    string message = 3;

    repeated string stack_trace_entries = 4;

    string code_filename = 5;

    int32 code_lineno = 6;

    string code_name = 7;

    google.protobuf.Any arbitrary_info = 16;
}
```

If the python package [googleapis-common-protos](https://pypi.org/project/googleapis-common-protos/) is installed, related python modules (in this case, `google.rpc.code_pb2.Code`) are available. But since no proto files are installed, I got the following error.

```
$ protoc --proto_path=. --python_out=. exc_info.proto
google/rpc/code.proto: File not found.
exc_info.proto: Import "google/rpc/code.proto" was not found or had errors.
exc_info.proto:14:5: "google.rpc.Code" is not defined.
```

How to use these google proto files in Python ? Do I have to `git clone` the repo and include every proto files when compiling ?

Answer (score 2):

Solved. I have to clone it.

https://github.com/googleapis/api-common-protos#using-these-protos

> If you are using protoc (or other similar tooling) to compile these
>   protos yourself, you will likely require a local copy. Clone this
>   repository to a convenient location and use --proto_path to specify
>   the root of this repository on your machine to the compiler.